# compilation error when a SIRD is added in the Play application

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I have a working project which uses `Play`'s compiled routes. I want to add `SIRD` route to handle some web services. The compiled routes would stay.

I created a `routes.users` package and added the following `UserRoutes` scala class in it.

```
package routes.users
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.routing.Router.Routes
import play.api.routing.SimpleRouter
import play.api.routing.sird._
import controllers.UserController

class UserRouter @Inject()(controller:UserController) extends SimpleRouter {

  override def routes:Routes = {
    case GET(p"/users/add") => controller.addUser();
  }
```

When I tried to compile the code, I got the following error.

```
error] error writing routes/users/UserRouter: C:\...\target\scala-2.12\classes/routes/users/UserRouter.class: C:\...\target\scala-2.12\classes\routes is not a directory
[error] error writing routes/users/UserRouter$$anonfun$routes$1: C:\...\target\scala-2.12\classes/routes/users/UserRouter$$anonfun$routes$1.class: C:\...\target\scala-2.12\classes\routes is not a directory
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

The code compiles and works if I remove `routes.users` package. What mistake am I making?

Comment: I think the problem is in the name. `routes.users` seem to be the issue. I changed it to `WSRouters.user` and things seem to work. Still diagnosing this. maybe `routes` is used for some internal purpose which is creating some conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as you commented, the problem is with the name.

I'm not entirely the exact details, but I'm pretty sure routes is used for reverse routing and I have attempted to make my own routes package before and its caused an issue for the same reason you are having right now. Seems like a naming conflict.

From [Play Framework Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaRouting#reverse-routing)